# `\left` `\right` not working properly with `\mathchoice`

Tags: math-mode, subscripts, superscripts, inline, displaystyle

I try to define `\norm` which gives `\left\|#1\right\|` in display math, while `\|#1\|` in inline math. I then use `\mathchoice` to implement this, but the final command doesn't work properly: the position of supper/subscript is wrong. How could I fix that?

[image]

MWE

```
\documentclass{report}
\def\mychoice#1#2{\mathchoice{#1}{#2}{#2}{#2}}
\newcommand{\normm}[1]{\mychoice{\left\|#1\right\|}{\|#1\|}}
\begin{document}
    \[
        \normm{\frac{1}{2}}^2_R\quad\textrm{but I meant}\quad\left\|\frac{1}{2}\right\|^2_R
    \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: why not use \left\right in textstyle?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Just because `\left` `\right` always cause uneven line spacing in text, and I really don't like it...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You may try `\left(x^2\right)^2` and `(x^2)^2` in text, then you can see the difference

Comment: You can set `\delimitershortfall` more agressively, but the major problem with `\left\right` is that it produces suboptimal  horizontal space and that applies to displaystyle as well, I can't think of any case where a standard sized delimiter would be OK in textstyle but you need sretchy in display

Comment: also the acceped answer of adding `{}` has the same effect of raising the final`^2`in that example, see`\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\delimitershortfall=2pt
\delimiterfactor=800
$\left(x^2\right)^2$ and $(x^2)^2$  and ${(x^2)}^2 $
\end{document}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You're right, this problem looks much more complicated than I've thought. Seems I need to do it manually.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If `\mathchoice{...}{...}{...}{...}` *expanded* to one of the alternatives, things would behave as you expected. But what it does is different: it appends a “choice item” (containing the four alternatives) to the current math list.

Basically, your superscript and subscript defined with `^2_R` apply to a math atom with an empty nucleus, whereas you would like them to apply to one of the alternatives of the `\mathchoice`. You'll obtain what you want if you wrap the `\mathchoice` within a pair of braces (which creates a subformula):

```
\def\mychoice#1#2{{\mathchoice{#1}{#2}{#2}{#2}}}
```

or, better:

```
\newcommand*{\mychoice}[2]{{\mathchoice{#1}{#2}{#2}{#2}}}
```

Now, let's use `\showlists` to see what happens under the hood without the additional braces:

```
\documentclass{report}
\newcommand*{\mychoice}[2]{\mathchoice{#1}{#2}{#2}{#2}}
\newcommand{\normm}[1]{\mychoice{\left\|#1\right\|}{\|#1\|}}

\begin{document}

\tracingonline=1
\showboxbreadth=\maxdimen \showboxdepth=\maxdimen
\[ \normm{\frac{1}{2}}^2_R \showlists \]

\end{document}
```

which prints:

```
### display math mode entered at line 9
\mathchoice
D\mathinner
D.\left"26B30D
D.\mathord
D..\fraction, thickness = default
D..\\mathord
D..\.\fam0 1
D../\mathord
D../.\fam0 2
D.\right"26B30D
T\mathord
T.\fam2 k
T\mathord
T.\fraction, thickness = default
T.\\mathord
T.\.\fam0 1
T./\mathord
T./.\fam0 2
T\mathord
T.\fam2 k
S\mathord
S.\fam2 k
S\mathord
S.\fraction, thickness = default
S.\\mathord
S.\.\fam0 1
S./\mathord
S./.\fam0 2
S\mathord
S.\fam2 k
s\mathord
s.\fam2 k
s\mathord
s.\fraction, thickness = default
s.\\mathord
s.\.\fam0 1
s./\mathord
s./.\fam0 2
s\mathord
s.\fam2 k
\mathord
^\fam0 2
_\fam1 R
```

The last three lines show a `\mathord` atom with an empty nucleus, a superscript and a subscript. The resulting PDF output is, as far as I can tell, identical to what would be obtained with:

```
\[ \normm{\frac{1}{2}} {}^2_R \]
```

[image]

If you put the additional braces around the `\mathchoice` item, the output of `\showlists` is instead:

```
\mathord
.\mathchoice
.D\mathinner
.D.\left"26B30D
.D.\mathord
.D..\fraction, thickness = default
.D..\\mathord
.D..\.\fam0 1
.D../\mathord
.D../.\fam0 2
.D.\right"26B30D
.T\mathord
.T.\fam2 k
.T\mathord
.T.\fraction, thickness = default
.T.\\mathord
.T.\.\fam0 1
.T./\mathord
.T./.\fam0 2
.T\mathord
.T.\fam2 k
.S\mathord
.S.\fam2 k
.S\mathord
.S.\fraction, thickness = default
.S.\\mathord
.S.\.\fam0 1
.S./\mathord
.S./.\fam0 2
.S\mathord
.S.\fam2 k
.s\mathord
.s.\fam2 k
.s\mathord
.s.\fraction, thickness = default
.s.\\mathord
.s.\.\fam0 1
.s./\mathord
.s./.\fam0 2
.s\mathord
.s.\fam2 k
^\fam0 2
_\fam1 R
```

In this case, the superscript and subscript apply to a `\mathord` atom that contains the whole `\mathchoice` in its nucleus.

[image]

Comment: Latex is always too subtle for me.... Great thanks for such simple solution!

Comment: Also for the detailed technique explanation

Comment: @JRen This is not LaTeX feature  but it is TeX feature.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do like that, even with braces around `\mathchoice`.

Compare the result, particularly the `\hat{X}` part.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand*{\mychoice}[2]{{\mathchoice{#1}{#2}{#2}{#2}}}
\newcommand{\normm}[1]{\mychoice{\left\|#1\right\|}{\|#1\|}}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\|}{\|}

\begin{document}

\[
\normm{\frac{1}{2}X}_R^2 \quad \normm{\hat{X}}_R^2 \quad \normm{X}_R^2
\]

\[
\norm*{\frac{1}{2}X}_R^2 \quad 
\norm{\hat{X}}_R^2 \quad 
\norm[\big]{\hat{X}}_R^2 \quad \norm{X}_R^2
\]

\end{document}
```

As you see `\normm{\hat{X}}` produces very oversized delimiters. With the `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` strategy you have much finer control.

[image]